# Why is this the definition of Quillen bifunctor?

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

This the definition of a Quillen bifunctor from [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Quillen+bifunctor).

> Let $C,D,E$ be model categories.
> $$ \otimes: C \times D \rightarrow E$$
> is a Quillen bifunctor if it preserves colimits in each variable and

---

> **Condition:** Given $f:a \rightarrow b, g:c \rightarrow d$, both cofibrations, the canonical pushout map
> $$ a \otimes d\sqcup_{a \otimes c} b \otimes c \rightarrow b \otimes d$$
> is a cofibration. And is trivial if either one of $f,g$ is trivial.

It is this condition that I don't know why it is justified.
If one were to define it, wouldn't the natural condition be:

> **Condition':** If $\otimes$ is a Quillen functor when $C \times D$ is equipped with the product model structure, i.e. a morphism is cof,fib,we, iff each component is.

Why is this not taken as the definition?

Comment: You probably know the answer by now, but for future readers: the short answer is that this is what is needed and satisfied in practice. The naïve version is, iirc, too weak to prove things we want but also too strong to be satisfied by things we care about.